# In C can I print the number of the an enum while input is a string/char, using enumeration?

Tags: c, enums

I'm trying to make a code that lets the user input a weekday (i.e monday), and then making it print which number the day is in the week.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum week {monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday};


int main (void) {

enum week day;

printf("Enter weekday:\n");
scanf(%c, &day);

printf("It is day number %d in the week, day+1"); // Enumeration is 0-indexed, which is why day+1 is added so that the 1st day is monday, otherwise monday would be the 0th day


}
```

This is what I came up with so far - can I do it like this?

Comment: It won't even compile. First come up with something that compiles.

Comment: Have you tried compiling this? Did it compile cleanly? If not, what did the compiler complain about?

Comment: Do you want the user to ht keys m,o,n,d,a,y and press Enter? Then no, you cannot do it like that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  You should post readable and compilable code — or near compilable code if your problem is about getting something to compile.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It would be sensible to use the `%d` format for input as well as output, but you need to fix up the `printf()` call too — you seem to have included your argument within your string, whereas you forgot to stringify the format argument to `scanf()`.

Comment: Sorry - I'm really new to coding, as thus I'm not entirely sure what you mean, when you say that I have included my argument within the string. stringify? - I will have to look that up! The compiler throws me the following error: main.c:13:8: error: expected expression before '%' token                                                                                              
  scanf(%d, &day);

Comment: It should be `"%c"` or `"%d"` or thereabouts.

Comment: The answer to the question seeking to escape from the code is "No".  That is, there isn't a simple way for the user to type `monday` and have the program convert that to the value of the `enum week` for `monday`.  You can add 1 to an enumeration, but there's no check or processing for `sunday + 1` being out of range or wrapping back to `monday`.  You would have add that. Similarly, you can subtract 1 but there's not spotting when that goes out of range or wrapping back to `sunday`. There's no built-in provision for converting the value in `day` into a string that matches the name of its value.

Comment: Thank you! That was a very helpful comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// scanf(%c, &day);
scanf("%c", &day);
```

Only reads 1 character into `day`.

---

Suggest adding an array of week day names.

Input a string.
Lop off trailing `\n`
Convert to lower case if desired. (not shown)
Test input against the 7 names.
Report results.

```
int main(void) {
  enum week {
    monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday
  };

  static const char *weekday_name[sunday - monday + 1] = { "monday", "tuesday",
      "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday" };

  printf("Enter weekday:\n");
  char buffer[80];
  fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
  buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = 0; // lop off trailing \r and/or \n

  enum week wdn;
  for (wdn = monday; wdn <= sunday; wdn++) {
    if (strcmp(weekday_name[wdn], buffer) == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (wdn > sunday) puts("Day not found");
  else printf("It is day number %d in the week\n", wdn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

I suggest using 7 if statements.

There are a number of problems with your code though.  As a first milestone, I suggest making the program just print out the day of the week the user input.  From there go to having the program output the numeric day value.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually in the language, `enum` are not supposed to be accessible by their number (although they *are*); in C++ the compiler is even free to assign them whatever code it wants, and you are not allowed to use them.

To cleanly achieve what you want, you should *explicitly assign them values*, like:
`enum week {monday = 1, tuesday = 2, ...};`
(or whatever numbers you want to use).

Comment: The question, though, is about C, not C++.  You should either remove the reference to C++ or relate what C++ handles to C.  Note that the first element in an enumeration is given the value 0 unless you override it.  In the question, day 0 is Monday.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. For some reason I thought this was about C++

Answer (score 0):

I suggest abandoning the `enum week`, write a function `int parseWeekdayName(char *)` returing 0-6, and set up a static array`char *nameOfWeekday[7] = { "Sunday", "Monday"...}`